# Hook not visible and modules issue

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Goodmorning everyone. I'm going crazy behind a very simple new hook.
I just wanted to add the share buttons in the blog articles, I added the hook in theme.yml as shown in the image, I reset the theme and the module but nothing to do, I don't see the hook if I try to insert the module.
Moreover from this insertion onwards I am no longer able to reset or uninstall the module, it returns me the error you see in the image. What am I doing wrong?
[img01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUPpm.png)
[img02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Nfm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your hook exists in the ps_hooks tables if not add it there.

Comment: I succeeded but it seems that the module is not suitable for sharing a blog article-
I got this error "Notice: Undefined index: product" :-|

Comment: your hook should accept a Product object as argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register it in the ps_hooks database,maybe the ideal can be to create a module, and in the installation register the hook and assign a template that shows what you need in the hook.

[Prestashop documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/sample-modules/grid-and-identifiable-object-form-hooks-usage/)

Comment: @sangkavr Did you find a solution?